# VSTS Deploy failed with error -1073740791

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm getting a very tricky error when I run my deployment task to my second environment on my release pipeline that I can't solve. Seems to be something related to NodeJS. We don't use note at all. And what is that `timer.c`? Any help?  I just pasted here the end of the log file where the error is. Let me know if the full log is needed and I will update my question.

```
2018-07-31T14:32:47.6409251Z ##[debug]Processing drop/Captura.PDV.Pagadoria.Web.deploy.cmd
2018-07-31T14:32:47.7084467Z ##[debug]Got download stream for item: drop/Captura.PDV.Pagadoria.Web.deploy-readme.txt
2018-07-31T14:32:47.7085150Z ##[debug]testing directory 'C:\vstsagent\A1\_work\r1\a\_Captura-CI\drop'
2018-07-31T14:32:47.7087739Z Downloading drop/Captura.PDV.Pagadoria.Web.deploy-readme.txt to C:\vstsagent\A1\_work\r1\a\_Captura-CI\drop\Captura.PDV.Pagadoria.Web.deploy-readme.txt
2018-07-31T14:32:47.7094967Z Assertion failed: new_time >= loop->time, file src\win\timer.c, line 37
2018-07-31T14:32:47.8022545Z ##[error]Exit code -1073740791 returned from process: file name 'C:\vstsagent\A1\externals\node\bin\node.exe', arguments '"C:\vstsagent\A1\_work\_tasks\DownloadBuildArtifacts_a433f589-fce1-4460-9ee6-44a624aeb1fb\0.137.2\main.js"'.
2018-07-31T14:32:47.8058568Z ##[debug]Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Util.ProcessExitCodeException: Exit code -1073740791 returned from process: file name 'C:\vstsagent\A1\externals\node\bin\node.exe', arguments '"C:\vstsagent\A1\_work\_tasks\DownloadBuildArtifacts_a433f589-fce1-4460-9ee6-44a624aeb1fb\0.137.2\main.js"'.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Util.ProcessInvoker.<ExecuteAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.ProcessInvokerWrapper.<ExecuteAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Handlers.DefaultStepHost.<ExecuteAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Handlers.NodeHandler.<RunAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.TaskRunner.<RunAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.StepsRunner.<RunStepAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
2018-07-31T14:32:47.8065131Z ##[section]Finishing: Download artifact - _Captura-CI
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem restarting the server. It is an EC2 instance on AWS.

https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues/1268#issuecomment-371829176

Comment: Since you problem has been solved, you can mark the answer.

Comment: I must wait 2 days in order to do that